# Searching history in Bash forward after backward?

Tags: bash, command-history

In Bash, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, I can search the command history backward. If I would like to search forward again, what shall I do?(The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> doesn't work.)

My Bash is: `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Ctrl-S should work. At least it works on my machine in an xterm. If this doesn't work, type `stty -ixon`.

Comment: Does your shell lock-up with `ctrl-s`, and recover with `ctrl-q`? If so you need to disable flow control. (tell us if it does, so we can give the correct help)

Comment: @richard: (1) I hit ctrl+q several times, and it seems ctrl+s works now. Why is it?  (2) Also does ctrl+s works only after during searching with ctrl+r?

Comment: With flow control, Ctrl-S stops the flow, while Ctrl-Q re-enables it; that's why it solves your problem. Flow control is useless nowadays. I suggest that you disable it with `stty -ixon` (put that in your shell startup file for interactive shells).

Comment: 2) you can only go forward, after going backward: you can not do forward to what you will type later, the computer is not clever enough to figure this out.

Comment: @vinc17, thanks. what is "the flow"? by flow control. do ou mean disabling the flow?

Comment: @richard Ctrl-S without Ctrl-R first can make sense if you have typed the up arrow several times (to go backward in the history).

Comment: @Tim See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control

Comment: Flow control was used to pause the output, useful if the computer outputting to fast, but not so fast that you can not see roughly where it is. These days it is useless, as the computer is way to fast to make it useful. (a bit of software could be fast enough to react, so it could be used there. Other flow control protocols are used in TCP for example) But the short story is that if you disable it, you will not miss it.

Answer (score 11):

Your tty probably has the `ixon` and `ixany` bits set.

`ixon` enables XON/XOFF flow-control, so when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, the tty device stops output. But `ixany` means that *any other key* will restart output, so most people don't notice it ever stopped.

Some people find flow-control useful, but you can disable it by running:

```
stty -ixon
```

and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> should work as expected for searching in bash.

You might want to add that to your `~/.bashrc`!